# Netgear Gigabit Switch Bringing Entire Network Down

Tags: networking, internet, power-supply, lan, power

*Hello everyone, I am using this post as a method of sharing how I solved my own problem and to hopefully help others as I was unable to find any other information regarding this topic. I will mark my answer to this question in the answers section.*

**The Problem:**
Netgear Gigabit Network Switch (GS116NA) shuts down entire network when plugged into a Comcast supplied modem/router combo.

In previous years, my network was only 10/100 because my ISP only supplied me with about 25/5 internet speeds. And I had no other devices on my network that I needed to communicate to other than to move small files around. These files would not be bottlenecked by this connection. I used Netgear 10/100 switches and cat5e cable (cat5 in some places) to connect my entire network which at the time was mostly wireless. Now, I have upgraded and my ISP now supplies me with 250/15 internet speeds and obviously, I was unable to get the full potential of my network using the connections prior. So I did what anyone would do and I upgraded all the cabling, AP's ad switches to gigabit. I did already have one Netgear switch that was gigabit, but it was at the end of a 150ft cat5e run and strangely would not work at all unless there was another Netgear switch (a 10/100 switch) supplying it. Using my standard modem would not work, it would only work when two switches were connected to each other.

Overall, I was really stumped here and have yet to find the solution to my issue. It seems as though I may need to just replace the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: The issue here is in the power supply. The Netgear switch I'm using requires at least 1.5A at 12v. The power supply that was previously connected was only rated for 750mA. I have not performed the tests to determine exactly why an underrated power supply would shut down the entire network. I doubt that it is power draw related as I would assume that the ports on my modem are protected against that sort of thing, but I could be wrong. We're talking about Comcast here.

Anywho, I hope this helps anyone who is having a similar issue. If your network shuts down and you're using a switch, check the PSU!